# Rails 3: Math between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I have the following structure:

```
parts model:
- title
- weight
- part_type_id

part_type model:
- quotation
```

I want to set a "price" for each part. The models are using associations (parts:has_one) and (part_types:belongs_to). This is ok.

So, basically what I'm doing is creating an virtual attribute like this:

```
class Parts < ActiveRecords::Base
  ..
  attr_accessor :price

  def price
    quotation = PartType.find(self.part_type_id).quotation
    price = self.weight * quotation
  end
end
```

And I can call it from the view like this:

```
<% @parts.each do |part| %>
   <%= part.title %>
   <%= part.price %>
<% end %>
```

Is this the "right" way for doing this or how should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [`attr_reader`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000476) to be paranoid:

```
attr_reader :price
```

Changing the price on its own doesn't make much sense so, since they really are out to get you, it is best to do away with a whole class of possible bugs with that small change. Then you'd want to alter your accessor to directly work with the instance variable that `attr_reader` creates:

```
def price
    return @price if(@price)
    @price = PartType.find(self.part_type_id).quotation * self.weight
end
```

Presumably neither `nil` nor `false` are valid prices so you don't have to worry about computing the `@price` over and over again if `if(@price)` fails; the computation should only occur once as instance variables are automatically initialized to `nil` on first access.

Looks sensible enough to me other than the minor nit mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you for all the explanation, first I was confuse about using `attr_accessor` and `attr_reader`, but seems that if it will be a readonly attribute I really should go for `attr_reader`. So it's look okay this way.